# Passing variables from JS to PHP

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I'm trying to pass a variable from JS to PHP but so far no luck. I've been searching here for solution, but it seems that nothing helps..

Ok, I have php file with pagination:

```
$pagination .= '<li><a href="#" class="paginate_click" id="'.$i.'-page">'.$i.'</a></li>';
```

Paginate_click launches js function:

```
$(".paginate_click").click(function (e) {

    $("#results").prepend('<div class="loading-indication"><img src="ajax-loader.gif" /> Loading...</div>');

    var clicked_id = $(this).attr("id").split("-"); //ID of clicked element, split() to get page number.
    var page_num = parseInt(clicked_id[0]); //clicked_id[0] holds the page number we need 

    $('.paginate_click').removeClass('active'); //remove any active class

    //post page number and load returned data into result element
    //notice (page_num-1), subtract 1 to get actual starting point
    $("#results").load("views/fetch_articles.php", {'page':(page_num-1)}, function(){

    $(window).scrollTop(0);

    });

    $.post('views/articles_list.php', {'page':(page_num)});

    $(this).addClass('active'); //add active class to currently clicked element (style purpose)

    return false; //prevent going to herf link

});
```

In php file I need information which page of pagination I'm currently on so I want to retrieve page_num value back to my php. I tried this:

```
$.post('views/articles_list.php', {'page':(page_num)});
```

And in php:

```
$page_number = $_POST["page"];
```

I tried also many other options, but nothing helps. I thought it will be easier :/

As you probably noticed there's another php file (fetch_articles.php) and in this case $_POST["page"]; works. But for articles_list.php I can't use load function.

EDIT: What I want and entire code.

I have simple and nice pagination. The only problem is that it has no option for prev/next and it shows all the buttons. It's a problem when you have a lot of pages. So my idea is to shrink it down and instead of heaving 1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,15,16,17,18,19 and so on I want this:
prev,1,2,3...67,68,next. **To do this I need to pass to my php file an information about actual page**. With this variable I can calculate everything and organize my pagination with for/if/else statements.

The code.

articles_list.php:

```
<?php
include("../config/connection.php");
include('../config/css.php');

$results = mysqli_query($dbc_connection,"SELECT COUNT(*) FROM articles");
$get_total_rows = mysqli_fetch_array($results); //total records

//break total records into pages
$pages = ceil($get_total_rows[0]/$item_per_page);     

//create pagination
if($pages > 1)
{
$pagination = '';
$pagination .= '<ul class="paginate">';

for($i = 1; $i<=$pages; $i++)
{
    $pagination .= '<li><a href="#" class="paginate_click" id="'.$i.'-page">'.$i.'</a></li>';
}
$pagination .= '<li><a href="#" class="paginate_click" id="'.$page_number.'-page">'.$page_number.'</a></li>'; // only to check if variable is passed
$pagination .= '</ul>';
}

?><!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-1.9.0.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/pagination.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<?php $page_number = $_POST["page"];
echo $page_number; // only to check if variable is passed ?> 
<div id="results"></div>
<?php echo $pagination; ?>
</body>
</html>
```

pagination.js:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
$("#results").load("views/fetch_articles.php", {'page':0}, function() {$("#1-page").addClass('active');});  //initial page number to load

$(".paginate_click").click(function (e) {

    $("#results").prepend('<div class="loading-indication"><img src="ajax-loader.gif" /> Loading...</div>');

    var clicked_id = $(this).attr("id").split("-"); //ID of clicked element, split() to get page number.
    var page_num = parseInt(clicked_id[0]); //clicked_id[0] holds the page number we need 

    $('.paginate_click').removeClass('active'); //remove any active class

    //post page number and load returned data into result element
    //notice (page_num-1), subtract 1 to get actual starting point
    $("#results").load("views/fetch_articles.php", {'page':(page_num-1)}, function(){

    $(window).scrollTop(0);

    });

    $.post('views/articles_list.php', {page:page_num}, function(data){});

    $(this).addClass('active'); //add active class to currently clicked element (style purpose)

    return false; //prevent going to herf link

}); 
});
```

fetch_articles.php:

```
<?php

include("../config/connection.php"); //include config file

//sanitize post value
$page_number = filter_var($_POST["page"], FILTER_SANITIZE_NUMBER_INT, FILTER_FLAG_STRIP_HIGH);

//validate page number is really numaric
if(!is_numeric($page_number)){die('Invalid page number!');}

//get current starting point of records
$position = ($page_number * $item_per_page);

//Limit our results within a specified range. 
$result = mysqli_query($dbc_connection,"SELECT * FROM articles ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT $position, $item_per_page");

//output results from database

while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
{
?>
<h2><?php echo $row['title']; ?></h2>
<p><i><?php echo 'By '.$row['author']; ?></i></p>
<p><?php echo $row['header']; ?></p>
<a href="http://localhost/site/articles/<?php echo $row['slug'] ?>">Read</a><br>
<hr>
<?php
}

?>
```

Comment: There is no need to do 2 ajax requests simultaneously, you should do both things in one ajax request. Apart from that, how do you know it doesn't work? You are not doing anything with the output of your php script.

Comment: I tried to echo this, but no result.. <?php $page_number = $_POST["page"];
echo "I got your value! $page_number"; ?>

Comment: What do you mean, `no result`? You should add a function to display the results of your ajax call in the javascript.

Comment: Could you help me and show how? I'm new to JS...

Answer (score 0):

Try removing the parenthesis around `page_num`:

```
$.post('views/articles_list.php', {'page':page_num});
```

Answer (score 0):

You didn't said in which one of the requests you can't get the value you're trying to pass. So, I'm guessing it is in the first one:

```
$("#results").load(...);
```

The problem here is that you're using the **.load()** method, which is equivalent to **.get()**. So, when you try, in the PHP file to get **$_POST**["page"], it will not be there, because it is actually in the **$_GET** array.

Comment: No , this ones fine. I have an issue with the second. As Jeroen already suggested I need a function to display the result.

Answer (score 0):

I may be missing something here, but couldn't you just append a query string to the url manually?

```
$.post('views/articles_list.php?pn=' + page_num);
```

Then in your fetch_articles.php you just pull it off with

```
$page_number = $_GET["pn"];
```

If that fails you can always use a cookie.

Comment: No result. Firebug shows php?pn= but browser doesn't. I tried cookie and session but they didn't pass variable unless page was refreshed. And while I'm using ajax, it wasn't the option.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of

```
$.post('views/articles_list.php', {'page':(page_num)});
```

try

```
$.post('views/articles_list.php', {page:page_num}, function(data){ 
   console.log(data);
},'json');
```

And also double check if 'views/articles_list.php' is the correct path. If you were using Chrome, kindly read the parsing via right click -> inspect elements -> Network.

Addition(After posted your edit code) :-
Please remove the Doctype and HTML and leave something like this.

```
<?php
include("../config/connection.php");
include('../config/css.php');

$results = mysqli_query($dbc_connection,"SELECT COUNT(*) FROM articles");
$get_total_rows = mysqli_fetch_array($results); //total records

//break total records into pages
$pages = ceil($get_total_rows[0]/$item_per_page);     

//create pagination
if($pages > 1)
{
$pagination = '';
$pagination .= '<ul class="paginate">';

for($i = 1; $i<=$pages; $i++)
{
    $pagination .= '<li><a href="#" class="paginate_click" id="'.$i.'-page">'.$i.'</a></li>';
}
$pagination .= '<li><a href="#" class="paginate_click" id="'.$page_number.'-page">'.$page_number.'</a></li>'; // only to check if variable is passed
$pagination .= '</ul>';
}

//Assuming you're doing ajax here. so either pagination or page number posting back? if both try below.

$page_number = $_POST["page"];

echo json_encode(array("pagination"=>$pagination,"pageNumber"=>$page_number));

?>
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: Still nothing :( I pasted my whole code in EDIT section. It seems harder than I thought..

Comment: I have changed ajax but your new php code doesn't work. We can't delete div id="results" because js needs it :) $pagination and everythig else is fine, I just need to pass page_num from pagination.js to articles_list.php. Thats all.

Comment: Please tell me if your console return correct `$page_number`? Other than that what I can actually advice is shift the js processing part back to front page to practice MVC. Your php code should be just modelling(processing) and db query.

Comment: You mean firebug console? Yes, it shows 'page=12' under source. Also if I add  alert(page_num); to js function it shows correct value. But not with json...

Comment: And parameter in console under http://localhost/site/views/articles_list.php is: page 12 (I guess it's parameter, I use non-engish firebug).

Comment: so proven that you already get your `$page_number`, now the processing inside might be another question, I notice there is a jquery plugin you were trying with your pagination. Would you able to tell us what's the plugin you used?

Comment: I believe `pagination.js` doesn't available via jquery.com